# activiti kickstart - dropdown list error

Tags: alfresco, activiti

I'm using the Activiti Kickstart component (with the Eclipse plugin) and I'm having difficulties with the Dropdown list (from the Controls in the Palette) in the way that after I successfully export my workflow in Alfresco, all option values are missing.
Also, in the model.xml file generated automatically, I don't seem to find the proper constraint tags, with my values.
I'm very new with alfresco and activity, so please bear with me.

Thanks

Comment: Furthermore, it seems that any option values for the Dropdown list aren't saved; I closed and reopened the form and all my values were gone. Anyone?

Comment: Can you add more context? It's difficult to follow if there are no files. Maybe screenshots and add the links to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you followed the Alfresco Summit 2013 presentation? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S9x9uYKONSE

Comment: Hi Tahir and thank you for your answer. The link you provided is the one I followed also. In the video tutorial, at 05:46 the author places a dropdown list component called "Position type" with the values "Sales", "Marketing", "Engineering" etc. I do the same, I save it and I close and reopen the "start" form. When I reopened it, the dropdown list "Position type" still exists but there no values.

Comment: I use Eclipse 4.4.0 Java EE IDE for Web Developers and Activiti BPMN 2.0 Designer, version 5.15.

Comment: can you please confirm me that you're not having the same result?

Comment: Hi bluesony, it's indeed a bug. It's not working. I've tweeted this to the Activity guys and sure the'll fix it asap.

Comment: Hi Tahir. I also tried with Eclipse Indigo and Kepler (downloaded from the official site, both standard and jee versions) and received the same result.Even more, with Indigo, Eclipse closes automatically when I close the "start" form.Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi BlueSony, according to Activiti this is working for the, so I'm in the middle to figure out how it 'does' work for them.

Comment: Tahir, Activiti confirmed it as a bug: http://forums.activiti.org/content/activiti-kickstart-dropdown-list-error. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could anyone able to fix this issue?? I am still facing this while I am using Eclipse Luna.. ?

Comment: It should have been fixed. Have you installed the latest version?

Comment: @mansoor, until it's fixed, you can add manually the proper constraint tags with your values in the model.xml file.